# Google Login using React, Redux and Typescript - Login failed when I clicked sign in

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, redux, google-oauth

I am very beginner using TS, Redux and React. I am trying to implement Google Auth. The code is working but when I tried to login it has error in console. Login failed. What should I modify here on my code? I removed the node modules.
[Full source code on gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15NgzTy0SvW3HaDxvPzaa1MJCULwr1oQ9/view?usp=sharing) [[image: Here is the google console1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library like https://github.com/bjerkio/oidc-react (or auth0-react or okta-react) instead of implementing whole OIDC/OAuth 2.0 workflow. It is much more complicated and time consuming to cover all use cases implemented by these libraries.